# SQL Query joins to seemingly loop non existent matches in second table

Tags: sql, left-join, outer-join

I'm trying to write out a query that will output all cases where a User is not part of Role.

I am trying to limit this query to be simple as possible (no loops, *etc.*).

The table structure in my example is as so:

- Table `Team`:

  ```
  ID | UserID | RoleID
  ---+--------+-------
  1  | 0      | 0
  2  | 0      | 1
  3  | 0      | 2
  4  | 1      | 0
  5  | 1      | 2
  ```
- Table `Roles`:

  ```
  RoleID | Name
  -------+-----
  0      | AAA
  1      | BBB
  2      | CCC
  3      | DDD
  4      | EEE
  ```

Desired output:

```
UserID | RoleID
-------+-------
0      | 3
0      | 4
1      | 1
1      | 3
1      | 4
```

The code I was currently working with is:

```
SELECT *
FROM Team t
RIGHT OUTER JOIN Roles r ON t.RoleID = r.RoleID
LEFT JOIN Roles r1 ON t.RoleID = r1.RoleID
WHERE r.RoleID IS NULL
```

Comment: RIGHT JOIN combined with LEFT JOIN?!? No one can understand that...

Answer (score 0):

You can `CROSS JOIN` teams and roles to generate all possible combinations, and then use a `LEFT JOIN` anti-pattern to find out which combinations do not exist:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.UserID, r.RoleID
FROM Team t
CROSS JOIN Roles r
LEFT JOIN Team t1 ON t1.RoleID = r.RoleID AND t1.userID = t.UserID
WHERE t1.UserID IS NULL
ORDER BY t.UserID, r.RoleID
```

This **[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/apnkqVHsz3bqN6U2yMoiCW/0)** with your sample data returns:

```
| UserID | RoleID |
| ------ | ------ |
| 0      | 3      |
| 0      | 4      |
| 1      | 1      |
| 1      | 3      |
| 1      | 4      |
```

Answer (score 0):

I advocate generating the rows using a `cross join` and then filtering out the rows that already exist (using `left join` or `not in`):

```
select u.userid, r.roleid
from (select distinct userid from team) u cross join
     roles r left join
     team t
     on t.userid = u.userid and t.role_id = r.roleid
where t.userid is null;
```

If you have a separate table of users, you can use that instead of the subquery.  This should have two advantages over an approach using `select distinct`/`group by` in the outer query:

- An index can be used for the `(select distinct)` subquery for `u`.
- No processing is needed on the full result set to remove duplicates.